# How to start new table row in flex table

Tags: angular, flexbox

I am writing application in angular2, and in my ngFor loop I hav next data.

```
    1/04/17
    1/01/17
    Date
    ====
    A
    A
    Status 
    ====
    61.04
    45.73
    BSW 
    ====
```

How can I render new table. where data between `"====`" would be rows.

My HTML:

```
<span>{{data.text}}</span>
<span *ngIf="data.type === 'column'">
    ====
</span>
```

Expected result:

Date      | Status | BSW

1/04/17   | A | 61.04

1/01/17  | A | 45.73

Comment: The usual approach is to put in an element which is so wide that it forces a new row. You can find details in other questions here on SO.

Comment: How can i  implement this?